# Node.js YouTube downloader error code - 150

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube

I am trying to create a YouTube downloader using node.js and cheerio. It works fine for most videos but for certain videos on sending request to ***www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=id***, I get following response :

```
{ status: 'fail',
  errorcode: '150',
  errordetail: '0',
  enablecsi: '1',
  cver: '1.20160718',
  eventid: 'O0SOV_nzF9P4oAO9xoWIBQ',
  csi_page_type: 'embed',
  reason: 'This video contains content from Sony Pictures Networks India Pvt. Ltd.. It is restricted from playback on certain sites.\n<a href=\'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNNvi2hp1xM&feature=player_embedded\' target=\'_blank\'>Watch on YouTube</a>',
  c: 'WEB' }
```

How can I get the correct video_info file for such videos?